# Excluding Python Lists With Empty Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two lists, if list has data, I want to create a variable and assign it a name. If not, I want to disregard it. I then want to combine the list names into one list.

I'm having difficulty returning an empty value if there is no data in the list.

```
countries = ['America', 'France']
cities = []

if len(countries) != 0:
    country_name = 'country'
else:
    country_name = None
if len(cities) != 0:
    city_name = 'city'
else:
    city_name = None

region_names = [country_name, city_name]
```

Getting:

```
['country', None]
```

Want:

```
['country']
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this isn't working the way you want is `None` is still a NoneType object. So you can have a list of `NoneType` objects, or `NoneType` objects mixed with other types such as strings in your example.

If you wanted to keep the structure of your program similar, you could do something like

```py
countries = ['America', 'France']
cities = []
region_names = []

if len(countries) != 0:
    region_names.append('country')

if len(cities) != 0:
    region_names.append('city')
```

in this example we declare `region_names` up front and only append to the list when our conditions are met.